# Where does Magento Set a Quote Item's Price?

Tags: php, oop, magento

Whenever you load the cart page in Magento, the following code is run

```
$cart->init();
$cart->save();
```

One side effect of this is that the prices for any items in the cart are updated if the price of the product has been updated.  This actually updates the entry in `sales_flat_quote_item`.  I'm trying to track down where **in code** the price is updated on each quote item, and where each quote item is saved.

I know the myrid locations it **could** be set.  I'm hoping someone knows where it actually is set.  Magento 1.7x branch specifically, although info from all versions is welcome.

Answer (score 15, accepted):

From a high level, the code that starts the whole process are lines 464 and 465 of `Mage_Checkout_Model_Cart` :

```
 $this->getQuote()->collectTotals();
 $this->getQuote()->save();
```

The new product price is being set against the quote in `Mage_Sales_Model_Quote_Address_Total_Subtotal` in the `_initItem` method.  You will see `$item->setPrice` in the the if / else statement starting at line 104

Answer (score 24):

Dug this one up myself.  So there's this

```
#File: app/code/core/Mage/Sales/Model/Quote.php
foreach ($this->getAllAddresses() as $address) {
    ...
    $address->collectTotals();
    ...
}
```

which leads to this

```
#File: app/code/core/Mage/Sales/Model/Quote/Address.php
public function collectTotals()
{
    Mage::dispatchEvent($this->_eventPrefix . '_collect_totals_before', array($this->_eventObject => $this));
    foreach ($this->getTotalCollector()->getCollectors() as $model) {
        $model->collect($this);            
    }
    Mage::dispatchEvent($this->_eventPrefix . '_collect_totals_after', array($this->_eventObject => $this));
    return $this;
}
```

The `getTotalCollector` object returns a `sales/quote_address_total_collector` object, which loads a series of collector models from `global/sales/quote/totals` and calls `collect` on them.  The sub-total collector's `collect` method ultimately calls this

```
#File: app/code/core/Mage/Sales/Model/Quote/Address/Total/Subtotal.php
protected function _initItem($address, $item)
{
    //...
    if ($quoteItem->getParentItem() && $quoteItem->isChildrenCalculated()) {
        $finalPrice = $quoteItem->getParentItem()->getProduct()->getPriceModel()->getChildFinalPrice(
           $quoteItem->getParentItem()->getProduct(),
           $quoteItem->getParentItem()->getQty(),
           $quoteItem->getProduct(),
           $quoteItem->getQty()
        );
        $item->setPrice($finalPrice)
            ->setBaseOriginalPrice($finalPrice);
        $item->calcRowTotal();
    } else if (!$quoteItem->getParentItem()) {
        $finalPrice = $product->getFinalPrice($quoteItem->getQty());
        $item->setPrice($finalPrice)
            ->setBaseOriginalPrice($finalPrice);
        $item->calcRowTotal();
        $this->_addAmount($item->getRowTotal());
        $this->_addBaseAmount($item->getBaseRowTotal());
        $address->setTotalQty($address->getTotalQty() + $item->getQty());
    }    
    //...
}
```

and this is where the quote item gets it's price set/rest.

Answer (score 1):

If you are trying to do custom price changes on products in the cart, rather than extend and modify core classes, I use an observer sales_quote_save_before. It works great if you are trying to customize pricing (especially when I have products that can be custom length).